# Nemerle actors/coroutines & Mono Continuations

Tags: .net, mono, actor, continuations, nemerle

I found this article: http://www.mono-project.com/Continuations
So I have a few questions about it. 
Are there any implementations of erlang-style or (at least) scala-style actors for Nemerle based on this framework ?
If no, can anyone give an example of usage of this API, please.

Also is this continuation framework compatable with native Microsoft .NET CLR ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not seen a Nemerle actors library. However, the [ComputationExpressions](http://nemerle.org/wiki/index.php?title=ComputationExpression_macro) library is more powerful than continuations. It adds monad support to Nemerle, making it possible to implement continuations, coroutines, and many other features. You can find [examples](http://code.google.com/p/nemerle/source/browse/nemerle/trunk/snippets/ComputationExpressions/Test/AsyncTest.n) of implementing async using it in the snipets.

Comment: Thanks, it very interesting, but there are a lot of letters :) how this thing works? how async blocks do information exchange ? Is there something like "channels" ? And how this blocks scheduled ? I want something like erlang actor model where I can run a lot of "processes", executed in few threads and execution flow is switched by message-passing. Is this ComputationExpressions act like that?

Comment: Computation Expressions add monad support to the language, which could be used to implement actors. Channels and message is passing are some of the things one would have to implement to make an actor library.